# Working with to_char in where clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called room_allocation and want to extract details of those who were admitted in the month of January.So I have used the following query:

```
select * from room_allocation where to_char(adm_date,'Month')='January ';
```

the output for this is:

no data found

but when I give it as:

```
select to_char(adm_date,'Month') from room_allocation;
```

I get the output as:

```
TO_CHAR(ADM_DATE,'MONTH') 
October  
November  
December  
January
```

So please tell me why its not working in the first case.
Thank you.

Comment: Because `'January '` is a different value than `'January'`

Comment: and much better do with `where extract(month from adm_date) = 1` because January name can be different depending on NLS settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the format modifier `FM`. This will remove the trailing space.

```
SELECT * 
FROM room_allocation 
WHERE to_char(adm_date,'FMMonth')='January';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extra space you have at the end of January.

```
select * from room_allocation where to_char(adm_date,'Month')='January ';
```

Remove that and try it again

Comment: Hi The problem was not that space it was the trailing space which created the problem.Thanks for your suggestion.